# Input('type=number').each(function()) )}; não reconhece value só retorna NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, input

A função do título da pergunta só funciona retornando uma entrada do type=range como number no navegador. Já no Smarthphone só retorna NaN, provavelmente o *jquery.1.9.1.js* ou *jquery-mobile.1.4.5.js* não está compatível, alguma sugestão?

Código JS

```
<script>
     validar = function() {
         var soma = 0;
         $('input[type=number]').each(function() { //number devido ao código gerado pelo jquery mobile.
             soma += parseInt($(this).val());
         });
         console.log(soma);
         if (soma < 45) {
            location.href = "sua_pagina";
         }
         else{
             location.href="sua_pagina"
         }

     }      
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deves fazer a verificação se é número antes de incrementares:

```js
validar = function() {
         var soma = 0;
         $('input[type=number]').each(function() { //number devido ao código gerado pelo jquery mobile.
             var val = parseInt($(this).val());
             if(!isNaN(val)) {
                 soma += parseInt(val);
             }
         });
         console.log(soma);
         if (soma < 45) {
            //location.href = "sua_pagina";
         }
         else{
             //location.href="sua_pagina"
         }

     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<button onclick="validar();">Validar</button>
```

Comment: Deu tudo certo! O código funciona perfeitamente! Agradeço muito amigo!!

Comment: De nada @MarcílioAguiar